# Input Output for 8-bit ALU using FPGA board

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, alu

I am a newbie to xilinx so please excuse any stupidities in the code.

Ah so I am trying to design an **8-bit ALU** and the module is working perfectly on the simulation but we need to take inputs and display outputs on **FPGA** board.

Technically I should have used **RS-232** but since we just have an **8-bit input and 8 switches** are available, we are trying to code it this way.

However, the code does not compile and gives error 
`"expecting 'endmodule', found 'forever'"`.

I used `'forever'` and not `'always'` because always does not allow any instance to be instantiated within it.

Can anybody please help us figure out what is wrong with the code?

```
module main(out,in,switch);
output [7:0] out;
input [7:0] in;
input switch;
reg [7:0] a,b,select;
reg [1:0] count;
wire eq, comp, C8;
initial
begin
count = 2'b00;
select = 8'b0000_0000;
end
MyALU A(eq, comp, C8, out, a, b, 1'b0, select[0], select[1], select[2], select[3]);


forever
begin
if (switch)
    begin
        case (count)
        00: 
             begin
             a  = in;
             count = 2'b01;
             end
        01: 
             begin
             b  = in;
             count = 2'b10;
             end     
        10: 
             begin
             select  = in;
             A(eq, comp, C8, out, a, b, 1'b0, select[0], select[1], select[2], select[3]);
             count = 2'b00;
             end
        default
             a = in;
      endcase        
    end
end
```

Comment: Loops inside verilog must be inside some procedural block. Use `initial` before `forever`. Or remove `forever` and use `always @(*)` is finer way. `endmodule` is missing here.

Comment: Module instantiation is simply outside any procedural block. If multiple instances are required (which is not the case here), use `generate` block.

Answer (score 1):

Every module in verilog must end with the line `endmodule`. That is missing in your code. And try using `always@(*)` instead of `forever`. `forever` is not synthesizable and only used for verification with simulation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace the `forever` statement by `always @(*)`.
2. Remove this line from the case statement:
   `A(eq, comp, C8, out, a, b, 1'b0, select[0], select[1], select[2], select[3]);`
3. Add `endmodule` at the end.